# visual studio code IDE keyboard shortcuts customization

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I am new to visual studio code IDE. I know about keybinding.json and have been playing with what's in there. My question is if there is a file that stores a complete list of "command"s? eg: "workbench.action.splitEditor". Without a complete list of such command strings, I don't know what I can customize beyond what's in the keybinding file.

I have been using vs for more than 10 years, there are a few things I always do and I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same result in VSCode:
1. "alt+shift+l" -> go from current editing file from editor to solution explorer, and the cursor is on the current editing file in the solution explorer
2. "enter" -> hit enter key on a highlighted file name in solution explorer opens that file in editor area
3. "esc" -> hit esc key when focus is on solution explorer brings focus back to editing area. 
4. alt arrow keys -> when in editing area, performs column based editing

Answer (score 1):

You can see the complete list of actions > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the complete list that I can use (maybe it is the complete list of shortcuts that I can modify). For example, open a highlighted file name on the current editor view is ctrl+down arrow, this key mapping is not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. "alt+shift+l" -> go from current editing file from editor to solution explorer, and the cursor is on the current editing file in the solution explorer

Ctrl-Shift-E does exactly that now (as of 1.19.3, these are Windows hotkeys, other platforms slightly differ).

> 2. "enter" -> hit enter key on a highlighted file name in solution explorer opens that file in editor area

This works like that now out of box.

> 3. "esc" -> hit esc key when focus is on solution explorer brings focus back to editing area.

To go to VSCode editor from anywhere: Ctrl-1.

4. alt arrow keys -> when in editing area, performs column based editing

Ctrl+Alt+ ↑ / ↓ works for this now.

Comment: PS: This is an old question asked about very early version of VS code, but I was looking exactly for 1 and 3 myself today after switching from another IDE, so I thought I'd add the info for future users. :)